How to use Generic as Generic Parameter in TypeScript?
How to use Enumerable mixin with Vector?
The JS version works run it but I can't set types correctly.
// Enumerable abstract class
abstract class Enumerable<Collect, T> { // Error1 - can't use Collect<R>
  abstract [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<T>
  abstract collect<R>(...args: R[]): Collect<R>

  map<R>(op: (v: T) => R): Collect<R> {
    return this.collect(...[...this].map(op))
  }
}

// Vector using Enumerable
class Vector<T> {
  items: T[]
  constructor(...items: T[]) { this.items = items }

  *[Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<T> {
    for (const v of this.items) yield v
  }

  // Error2 - can't use `this<R>` as the return type
  collect<R>(...items: R[]): Vector<R> {
    // Error3 - can't use constructor without `any`
    return new (this.constructor as any)(...items)
  }
}

// Question4 - is it possible to incorporate this declaration
// in the `extend` helper?
interface Vector<T> extends Enumerable<Vector, T> {}
extend(Vector.prototype, Enumerable.prototype)

// Test
const v = new Vector(1, 2, 3)
console.log([...v.map(v => v * 2)])

// Helpers
function extend(o: object, props: object): void {
  for (let k of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(props)) {
    if (k == 'constructor' || o.hasOwnProperty(k)) continue
    Object.defineProperty(o, k, { 
      value: (props as any)[k], 
      enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true 
    })
  }
}


Error1 - how to specify generic result type Collect<R> as a parameter of the Enumerable?
Error2 - a minor error, it works, but would be even better if it was specified as something like this<R> instead of Vector<R>.
Error3 - also a minor error, can't use constructor without any it doesn't recognise constructor function signature.
Question4 - is it possible to somehow incorporate the interface Vector<T> extends Enumerable<Vector, T> {} in the extend helper to avoid typing it very time?

The inheritance is not used because there are multiple such mixins that needs to be included and inheritance allows only one parent.

This post is clearly asking multiple questions. Please [edit] this to ask a single primary question, or it risks being closed with "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."

I've had your example fixed with several notes for you.

Error1 - how to specify generic result type Collect as a parameter of the Enumerable?

You won't achieve extra strict typing with that. But you can add extra constraint to result type via type/interface. For now it's empty, but it can be filled with some extras.

Error2 - a minor error, it works, but would be even better if it was
specified as something like this instead of Vector.

Use just this if you want. But I would rather advice you to use Vector here, because you are not returning the same object.

Error3 - also a minor error, can't use constructor without any it
doesn't recognise constructor function signature.

Typescript does not infer the type of constructor to be anything beyond Function. You need add some type casting here, but it can be more strict than any.

Question4 - is it possible to somehow incorporate the interface
Vector extends Enumerable<Vector, T> {} in the extend helper to
avoid typing it very time?

You can. The way of doing it is described in typescript documentation.
P.s. I think that this particular example might be done with regular inheritance without using mixin patterns. In case if it was made intensionally just to demonstrate your problem, you can proceed. Otherwise I would advice you to consider using inheritance instead.
Despite I've been using this pattern myself, in my opinion mixins in typescript are flawed and should be avoided.
Here is the code snippet which worked for me:
// Enumerable abstract class

interface Collection<T>{ }

interface IEnumerable<T, R, RCol extends Collection<T>> {
    map<R>(op: (v: T) => R): RCol;
}

abstract class Enumerable<T, R, RCol extends Collection<T>> implements IEnumerable<T, R, RCol>{
    // Error1 - can't use Collect<R>
    abstract [Symbol.iterator](): Iterator<T>
    abstract collect<T>(...args: T[]): RCol

    map<R>(op: (v: T) => R): RCol {
        return this.collect(...[...this].map(op))
    }
}

// Vector using Enumerable
class Vector<T> {
    items: T[]
    constructor(...items: T[]) { this.items = items }

    *[Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<T> {
        for (const v of this.items) yield v
    }

    collect<T>(...items: T[]): Vector<T> {
        return new (this.constructor as typeof Vector<T>)(...items)
    }
}

interface Vector<T> extends IEnumerable<T, T, Vector<T>>{}

extend(Vector.prototype, Enumerable.prototype)

// Test
const v = new Vector(1, 2, 3)
console.log([...v.map(v => v * 2)])

// Helpers
function extend(o: object, props: object): void {
    for (let k of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(props)) {
        if (k == 'constructor' || o.hasOwnProperty(k)) continue
        Object.defineProperty(o, k, {
            value: (props as any)[k],
            enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true
        })
    }
}

